# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssServiceException: 'Invalid argument value. Parameter name: cherryPickToCreate'

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am getting the following error:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssServiceException: 'Invalid argument value.
Parameter name: cherryPickToCreate'
```

I'm trying to cherry-pick a set of commits into a new branch:

```
GitAsyncRefOperationParameters gitAsyncRefOperationParameters = new GitAsyncRefOperationParameters 
{ 
     GeneratedRefName = "refs/heads/master", 
     OntoRefName = "refs/heads/feature/testbranch", 
     Repository = repository, 
     Source = new GitAsyncRefOperationSource { CommitList = commits.ToArray() } 
};

var result = gitClient.CreateCherryPickAsync(gitAsyncRefOperationParameters, projectName, repoName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set `GeneratedRefName` parameter to `"refs/heads/master"`.

This property `GeneratedRefName` is the name of the cherry-pick branch to be created. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gitasyncrefoperationparameters?view=azure-devops-dotnet#properties).

[image]

From the UI, the `GeneratedRefName` is the `Topic branch name required` field as below screenshot highlighted, the `OntoRefName` is the `Target branch` ref name.

[image]

So you need to change your `GeneratedRefName` in your code. For example:

```
GitAsyncRefOperationParameters gitAsyncRefOperationParameters = new GitAsyncRefOperationParameters 
{ 
     GeneratedRefName = "refs/heads/feature/commits-on-mater", 
     OntoRefName = "refs/heads/master", 
     Repository = repository, 
     Source = new GitAsyncRefOperationSource { CommitList = commits.ToArray() } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also of note: all branches are case sensitive. You *may* encounter this error if your OntoRefName does not match within the bounds of case sensitivity.